# how to add onclick event to dynamically added button

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to add on click event for a button which is created dynamically

```js
$("tr").html("<button class='new'><span>next-</span></button>" + OriginalContent + "")

$('body').on('click', 'button .new', function() {
  //Some 
});
```

but its not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove between selector as space in selector indicate matching against descendants.

```
$("tr").on('click', 'button.new', function () {
```

Always use *staticParentElement* when using Event delegation for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.new', function () {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `button` and `.new`. Otherwise you will only watch `.new` elements inside of `button`, which will never happen.

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.new', function () {
    // ...
});
```